# How to compare strings based on a specific number of characters

Tags: python, character, string-comparison

I want to create a program that takes keyboard input for a string comparison based on the number of characters entered. So for example, let's say the number of characters entered is 3 and the two strings are "tommy" and "tomatos"... it would compare "tom" and "tom" and would determine that the strings are equal.

I'm just starting out with python. I know how to do the string comparison but I don't know how to incorporate the character comparison. I haven't found any resources online that demonstrate this particular thing I want to do.

```
s1 = input ("enter first string: ") 
s2 = input ("enter second string: ") 
n = input ("number of characters: ") 

if s1==s2:
 print(f'{s1} is equal than {s2}')
elif s1>s2:
 print (f'{s1} is greater than {s2}')
elif s1<s2:
 print (f'{s1} is less than {s2}')
else: 
 print ("Error")
```

This code doesn't have the character comparison. The code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can *slice* the strings, such that only the first `n` characters are retained:

```
s1 = input('enter first string: ') 
s2 = input('enter second string: ') 
n = int(input('number of characters: '))
s1 = s1[:n]
s2 = s2[:n]

if s1 == s2:
 print(f'{s1} is equal than {s2}')
elif s1 > s2:
 print (f'{s1} is greater than {s2}')
elif s1 < s2:
 print (f'{s1} is less than {s2}')
else: 
 print ("Error")
```

Comment: perhaps you had to preserve s1 and s2? (Depends all on the full context of this code)
It might be better to write `s1_first_n = s1[:n]` and them use this var in the comparisons.
same for s2 of course.

The first message might be changed as well to be accurate to something like.
`f'the first {n} characters of {s1} and s{2} are equal`

Answer (score 0):

you have to compare only the first n characters of each string.

to get the first characters of the string s1 use

```
s1[:n]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of regular expressions. By the use of "re.match", if both substrings match, it would print True, false otherwise.

```
import re

s1 = input('enter first string: ') 
s2 = input('enter second string: ') 
n = int(input('number of characters: '))

print(re.match(s1[:n],s2[:n]))
```

Comment: using re to match strings this way is not really such a good idea.
just imagine the first two character int the string would be a "^" followed by  another letter for example "^a" Many other comparisons with strings containing backslashes or '(' or '[' would fail as well.

Comment: I only started recently to be a little more active on SO.
I just downvoted this answer as it can give wrong results. Only afterwards I noticed, that @kirti desai is a rather new member of SO and that I might have  'killed' his reputation. 

So SO experts. What's the best / friendliest way to handle such situations?

In particular if one really wanted to use regexps (though not really advantageous in this particular case) one could do something like
`print(re.match(re.escape(s1[:n]), s2[:n]))`

Comment: You might have killed my reputation but made me more curious about using regex practically. And it seems I misunderstood the question. I thought he just wanted if the sliced strings match or not. Thanks